# How to fix admob revenue issue

Tags: android, admob

I had uploaded my app at playStore before a month containing ads (via Google AdMob SDK),everything working fine .Ads are showing and revenue generating as per click and impressions .But Suddenly i have checked and found no any click /impression /revenue is there from today morning , no event is occurred as per firebase console...Even Ads are showing in my app and users also interacting with the app, even analytics data ,no of active user and all also showing at firebase console but the problem is no event data and impression / ads click event info is there.                                                                               I don' t know what is happening !!

Answer (score -1):

Apparently is a [general problem](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/5307790?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks,   Yes It's a general problem ,don;t require any action  automatically  everything working fine ,all events and revenue gets updated.